# How to set default task for parallel tasks in gulp 3.9

Tags: javascript, gulp

Hello guys i am trying to run parallel tasks but my code does not work.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
        return gulp.src('app/scss/*.scss')
                .pipe(sass())
                .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
        }),

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
        return gulp.src('app/js/*.js')
                .pipe(jshint())
                .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
                .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
                .pipe(uglify())
                .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
        }),
gulp.task('images', function(){
        return gulp.src('app/img/*')
                .pipe(imagemin())
                .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));
        }),
gulp.task('watch', function(){
        gulp.watch('app/scss/*.scss', 'sass');
        gulp.watch('app/js/*js', 'scripts');
        gulpt.watch('app/img/*', 'images');
        }),


gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'scripts', 'images', 'watch']);
```

Tahnks you

Answer (score 0):

When watching files using `gulp.watch`, the second parameter should be an array of strings, not a single string.

Also there is a typo where you spelled `gulpt` instead of `gulp`.

The following works just fine:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
        gulp.watch('app/scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
        gulp.watch('app/js/*js', ['scripts']);
        gulp.watch('app/img/*', ['images']);
        }),
```